# How can the Compiler automatically infer the Types of a Multi Generic Type SwiftUI View?

Tags: swift, xcode, generics, swiftui, functional-programming

**Context**

I have a generic `SwiftUI View` that has two generic types. The first one needs to be specified manually while the second one could be inferred by the content passed to its `Initialiser`.

However, the `Compiler` forces me to specify both generic types manually when using the View. This results in very complex definitions like in the example below.

---

**Code**

```swift
protocol Entity {
    static var name: String { get }
}

struct EntityView<E: Entity, Content: View>: View {
    private let content: Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(E.name)

            content
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView {
    var body: some View {
        EntityView<Profile, TupleView<(HStack<EmptyView>, HStack<EmptyView>, Text)>> { // This is obviously not clean to define manually.
            HStack { ... }

            HStack { ... }

            Text("Hello World")
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Question**

Is there any "cleaner" way to achieve this functionality? Is it possible to somehow only define the generic type that cannot be inferred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift needs to either infer *all* the type parameters, or *all* the type parameters have to be specified explicitly.

One place from which Swift infers type parameters is the parameter list. Therefore, to make it "infer" `E` as well, add a parameter with `E.Type` in it.

```
init(_ type: E.Type, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
    self.content = content()
}
```

Then, when using the view, pass `Profile.self`:

```
EntityView(Profile.self) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, this solved the problem. However, why do you have to specify `Profile` as `Profile.self` in the init params when `Profile` is sufficient in the generic type declaration?

Comment: @christophriepe `Profile` is a type, which cannot be used as an argument. `Profile.self` is an expression of type `Profile.Type`, which can be used as an argument.